# Two ForEach Loops In PHP With Array Of Objects

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am using php to query MySQL and am returning an array of objects.

I then iterate the array by using `foreach ($sql as $res) {`

In those query results in `$sql` I need to also iterate one of the fields called `storeName`

How can I create a second `foreach` loop to iterate over each `storeName` in `$res`

Comment: `foreach ($res['storeName'] as $var)`?

Comment: If I try that I get an error ``CANNOT USE OBJECT OF TYPE STDCLASS AS ARRAY``

Comment: `foreach ($res->storeName as $var)` then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `->` notation if `$res` is **object**:

```
foreach ($sql as $res) {
    foreach ($res->storeName as $store) {
        print_r($store);    // or whatever else
    }
}
```

Comment: that gives me the value for ``$store`` would I still access the ``$res`` elements like ``$res->fieldName``

Comment: Yes, every property of object can be accessed via `->field` notation.